# Ensure callback to execute last

Tags: javascript

```
var a = function(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Hello"); }, 1000);
    callback(b);
}
var b = function(){
    console.log("Done");
}
a(b);
```

I notice that since javascript is asynchronous, the code above will show "Done" before "Hello".

However, I am curious that for the following code, will callback(j) ever be executed before j = JSON.parse(randomString) if the function JSON.parse took too long to parse the string? Which the j passed into callback function will be null.
If so, how do I prevent such case?

```
var randomString = '[{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}]';
var a = function(callback){
    var j;
    j = JSON.parse(randomString);
    callback(j);
}
var b = function(j){
    console.log("Done: " + JSON.stringify(j));
}
a(b);
```

Comment: who told you `js` is `asynchronous` ?

Comment: `JSON.parse` is not asynchronous. If takes too long, it will just halt everything untill it is finished.

Comment: @UsmanRana I thought that all functions in js is asynchronous, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is *not* asynchronous. What is does have is a lack of distinguishment between which *functions* are and are not synchronous.

If you write a javascript program that looks like this:

```
function x() {
  return "Hello";
}

function y() {
  return "World";
}

console.log(x());
console.log(y());
```

You will *always* produce "Hello World" in your console. `setTimeout()` is an asynchronous function and it is unclear without reading the documentation on the function that this is so. Because there is no distinct `Async` tag, it can be difficult to know what order code will execute in.

As a general rule, `setTimeout()` and any ajax call are asynchronous, and the rest behave synchronously. If you want to ensure synchronous functionality on things like `setTimeout()` try using promises, or embed your desired callback into the default callback event. ex:

```
function a(cb) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log("Hello, "); cb() }, 1000)
}

function b() {
  console.log("World");
}

a(b);
```

This will return `Hello, World` as intended.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. So does it mean I can assume most javascript statements and functions execute synchronously unless any asynchronous function is used?

Comment: That is exactly what that means, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I am curious that for the following code, will `callback(j)` ever be executed before `j = JSON.parse(randomString)` if the function `JSON.parse` took too long to parse the string?

No. `JSON.parse` is a synchronous function.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet, you are using setTimeOut. I will recommend to read more about it here :-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

This will help you understand why "Done" is shown before "Hello".

Second code snippet behavior is going to be different than first one. And JS is a synchronous language and using timer functions like setTimeout, you can mimic async behavior

Comment: Will do. Thanks !